# Need help getting started with making REST services using GAE

Tags: eclipse, web-services, google-app-engine, rest, soap

I've just started on a small project to create some REST services using Google App Engine and Java. I'm new to both technologies, but I've done some reading on both. I'm familiar with SOAP (have used them previously), and I think I understand the conceptual differences between REST and SOAP.

Currently I need info regarding two things:

1) I'm trying to find some tutorial which builds a simple REST service from scratch for deploying on Google App Engine (GAE). The simpler the better, but it should have at least a few routing options. I don't need any UI, if that matters.

2) Which RESTful Framework should I use with Google App Engine. Again, simplicity is what I'd like, and something which has tutorials and a newcomer can easily grasp.

My ultimate goal is to just write a REST wrapper with multiple routing options, which eventual consumes some pre-existing SOAP services and returns their results.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked out Google Cloud Endpoints for creating a REST service? Its pretty simple and straightforward, also has support for OAuth.

Answer (score -1):

I would give [Jello framework](http://jello-framework.com/) a try. It offers a clean, and simple to follow, JSON format and provides a very powerful and comprehensive RESTful implementation that follows the OData specification.

Here is Jello's REST development guide: http://jello-framework.com/guide/rest.html

Comment: Disagree with Ronak. The answer (to the call for help with REST) is a suggestion to use Jello, and details on why are included in the answer. Note to Yoram, [still] it would improve the answer to include some of the requested tutorials directly here.

Comment: So I am a little confused. Should I include link references or not?
Based on Barett comment, I added a link to the Jello REST guide.